# Python dataframe group by following values

Tags: python, datetime, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am looking for the best pythonic way to group the sum of values that follow each other from hour to hour. Example: I have the following Dataframe with the columns 'date' and'rainfall' and I have added an example of the desired result :

```
        date        rainfall    RE
    31/12/17 23:00  0.88    None
    01/01/18 00:00  0.38    1.26
    01/01/18 01:00  0       None
    01/01/18 02:00  0.22    0.22
    01/01/18 03:00  0       None
    01/01/18 04:00  0       None
    01/01/18 13:00  0       None
    01/01/18 14:00  0       None
    01/01/18 15:00  0.55    0.55
    01/01/18 16:00  0       None
    01/01/18 17:00  1.31    1.31
    01/01/18 18:00  0       None
    01/01/18 19:00  0.49    0.49
    01/01/18 20:00  0       None
    01/01/18 21:00  0       None
    01/01/18 22:00  0       None
    01/01/18 23:00  0       None
    02/01/18 00:00  0.7     None
    02/01/18 01:00  0.22    None
    02/01/18 02:00  0.61    None
    02/01/18 03:00  0.42    1.95
    02/01/18 04:00  0       None
    02/01/18 05:00  1.69    1.69
    02/01/18 06:00  0       None
    02/01/18 07:00  0       None
    02/01/18 08:00  0       None
```

I hope to be clear,

thanks a lot for your help,

Rémy

Comment: Think he's meaning a 'rolling_sum'

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you want is a rolling sum.
The following will output a Pandas Series of the rolling sums of 'rainfall' over 2 periods

```
df['rainfall'].rolling(2).sum()
```

Ofcourse, your `DataFrame` must stay sorted as you show in your example.

adding it as a part of your DataFrame would be:

```
df['rainfall_rolling_sum'] = df['rainfall'].rolling(2).sum()
```

**EDIT1:**

If you mean you just want to accumulate the rainfall use:

```
df['rainfall_cumsum'] = df['rainfall'].cumsum()
```

as the function `cumsum()` is accumulative sum

**EDIT2:**

```
rf_not_zero = df['rainfall'] != 0
df['rainfall_accum'] = df['rainfall'].cumsum()-df['rainfall'].cumsum().where(~df_not_zero).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Eran for this quick answer, but it does not work as expected. If you look at from the date "02/01/18 00:00", there is 4 values to add and not only 2.
Thanks again,
Rémy

Comment: Do you mean just accumulate the rainfall ?

Comment: Yes, but only when I have a rainfall event over **several consecutive** hours.
Thanks. Rémy

Comment: @R.Claverie Only took the whole day to understand :>

Answer (score 0):

Okey it is not the best, but when you have big dataframes this could be a simple approach. (If it rains at the beginning or at the end, this will be ignored in this example. See Warning)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# generate pseudo dataframe
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2012', periods=20, freq='H')
rain = np.random.choice([0,0.5,1,2], size=20, p=[0.4,0.2,0.2,0.2])

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['data'] = rng
df['rain'] = rain

# convert rain to boolean
df['is_rain'] = df['rain'] > 0

# shift rain for one slot to recognice if the state has changed
data = list(df['is_rain'].values[0:-1])
shifted = [data[0]]
shifted.extend(data)
df['is_rain_next'] = shifted

# get start and endpoints of rain (the end has to be excluded! 
# it is always the next period, when it isn't raining anymore)
df['rain_start'] = df['is_rain'] < df['is_rain_next']
df['rain_end'] = df['is_rain'] > df['is_rain_next']

# this are the starts and ends you can use them for getting the groups from dataframe
df[df['rain_start']].index
df[df['rain_end']].index
```

**Warning**: The arrays can have different sizes, thats caused by the unknown state at the end and at the beginning. So check if the first element in rain_end smaller than the first element in rain_start than you can delete it. Also if the last element of rain_start is greater than the last element of rain_end (sound logical i think)